# Get form data in JSON format for multiple fields of same name

Tags: jquery, json

Hello I am building a form table which have multiple same names for the rows. I want to submit the form table in JSON format where I am using a plugin.
Link - [Serialize JSON form plugin](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON)

with `$("#form").serializeJSON();`. With this I am only getting the last field in JSON format. It is replacing all the fields with the same name and have replaced it with the last field.

I wish to show all the fields in JSON format. 
For eg -

```
[
    {
        "field1": "id1",
        "field2": "dsda",
        "field3": "dsda",
    },
    {
        "field1": "id2",
        "field2": "dsda",
        "field3": "dsda",
    },
    {
        "field1": "id3",
        "field2": "dsda",
        "field3": "dsda",
    },
]
```

Instead I am only getting -

```
[
    {
        "field1": "id3",
        "field2": "dsda",
        "field3": "dsda",
    },
]
```

Here is my code -

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var jsonForm = $("#form").serializeJSON();
  console.log(jsonForm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.serializeJSON/2.9.0/jquery.serializejson.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="otherpage.html">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Field 1</th>
        <th>Field 2</th>
        <th>Field 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="field1" value="id1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field2" value="dsda"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field3" value="dsda"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="field1" value="id2"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field2" value="dsda"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field3" value="dsda"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="field1" value="id3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field2" value="dsda"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="field3" value="dsda"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" name="button" id="button">Serialize</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two or more fields with the same name in one form, instead you need to tell the html it's an array by adding [] at the end of the name for each same name, for example

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="field1[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="field2[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="field3[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="field1[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="field2[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="field3[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the output he is looking for. The output of this would be `{field1: ["id1", "id2","id3"], ...}`

Comment: Well, serializeJSON is not a function in jQuery so he's probably using some custom function, but still, he wouldn't be able to serialize the form data like he wanted without this fix. https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/bynaK/ using this serializeFormJSON function with the fix I provided would give him similar result he wanted.

Comment: Your solution definitely helped me and possibly many others. Just want to clear a concept. Adding [] at the end of input names changes nothing in HTML, and it sends data like it does before. It's server-side which manipulates it into something useful like an array.